# Scheduled Pages not publishing - Error Id 5542

Tags: 2013, publishing-page, schedule

My client has a News area, and has pages (news items) scheduled to be published but occasionally they fail to publish.

- We've given them a comprehensive guide as to how to schedule a page to be published, but they say they're following the correct process and it's still happening.
- I've checked the timer job 'Scheduled Unpublish' and it's running correctly.
- I've checked the error logs and there are no issues when pages are scheduled to be published.

Can anyone give me further advice? What else should I be checking?

Comment: I've found this error in the ULS log files, has anyone come accross it befoe? 5542 Critical Scheduled approval skipped for file: '/news/Pages/Temporary_wales_today_announced.aspx' due to unexpected file status or list state. db0eb69d-4858-30e2-6c24-d9f9ad11bc97